# Are object properties hoisted in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript hoist object properties (see use case below) ?

(Looking around, I've seen that variables are hoisted as well - are object properties simply a special case of variable hoisting?)

```
let obj = {};

$(".hey").each((i, obj) => {
  $(obj).click(obj.hey);
});

obj.hey = () => {
  $("#hey").html("Hey!");
};
```

Comment: It won't work if the page has an element with id "hey". It only "works" because the jQuery `.each()` loop doesn't run. The object property assignment below the `.each()` loop is definitely not hoisted.

Comment: @Tushar good point - even if there were a "hey" element, that code in the `.each()` callback won't do anything anyway, and the reference to `obj.hey` will simply be `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.hey` not `#hey` - `$(obj)` creates a new jQuery element from each selected object.

Comment: Yes my initial comment is incorrect. The callback will run, but nothing will really come of it since `obj.hey` is `undefined` at that point. (The comment is correct about the assignment not being hoisted.)

Comment: Ah ok - it doesn't work on click, but it doesn't throw any errors either.  So, the answer to my question is that object properties are not hoisted.  Pointy, since you said this first feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Also note that there's a [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let) when using `let`, and in your code `obj` is the element, as you're using the same variable name for the argument in `each`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/w9nujstv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no**, object property assignments are not hoisted. That's just a simple assignment expression.

The code you posted won't encounter any errors, because a *reference* to an undefined property is just an expression whose value is `undefined`.  Thus, the `.each()` loop asks jQuery to establish an event handler but passes it `undefined`, which will either do nothing or, possibly, trigger a "click" event on the target elements.